# Java: Parallel moving balls

Tags: java, applet

I made a program in java that is supposed to create 10 balles appearing and moving randomly, the balls-Threads are supposed to run in parallel, unfortunately the program does not compile. Does anyone know why ?
I get the following error for each Threads :

```
package movement;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;



public class Ball {
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius = 10;
    public Graphics g;
    int dx, dy, n = 0;

    Ball(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void move() {
        Random randomX = new Random();
        Random randomY = new Random();
        Random randomN = new Random();
        paint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        dx = (int) (Math.pow(-1, n) * randomX.nextInt(5));
        dy = (int) (Math.pow(-1, n) * randomY.nextInt(5));
        n = randomN.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }

    public void paint() {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(x + 100, y + 100, radius, radius);
    }

}
```

---

```
package movement;


class BallMovement implements Runnable {
    private final Ball ball;

    BallMovement(Ball ball) {
        this.ball = ball;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ball.move();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package movement;

        import java.applet.Applet;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Random;

public class StartingPoint extends Applet {

    public int startX, startY;
    private static final int nbBalles = 10;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Ball> BallList = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbBalles; i++) {
            Random randX = new Random();
            Random randY = new Random();
            startX = randX.nextInt(500) + 1;
            startY = randY.nextInt(500) + 1;
            BallList.add(new Ball(startX, startY));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Iterator<Ball> it = BallList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Ball ball = it.next();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new BallMovement(ball));
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" 
java.lang.NullPointerException at movement.Ball.paint(Ball.java:40) 
at movement.Ball.move(Ball.java:23) 
at movement.BallMovement.run(BallMovement.java:13) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: What do the compilation errors tell you?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error,                            Exception in thread "Thread-5"          java.lang.NullPointerException
 at movement.Ball.paint(Ball.java:40)
 at movement.Ball.move(Ball.java:23)
 at movement.BallMovement.run(BallMovement.java:13)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Comment: It compiles, but you get an exception at runtime.

Comment: Your **Graphics object** is `null`

Comment: thanks for the answers, do you know what can I do to correct it ? I'm new to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to get the `Graphics` object from the `void paint(Graphics g)` method of the `Applet`.

```
public class StartingPoint extends Applet {

    public int startX, startY;
    private static final int nbBalles = 10;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Ball> BallList = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    ...

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
         for(Ball ball : BallList)
         {
             ball.paint(g);
         }
    }
}
```

and in Ball, change the `paint()` method to `paint(Graphics g)`.

and don't call `paint()` from `move()`, and don't have a `Graphics` variable in the `Ball` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this field:

```
public Graphics g;
```

when used in this method.

```
public void paint() {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(x + 100, y + 100, radius, radius);
}
```

Your `g` field that you are referencing is not initialised.

You can fix it by changing your ball constructor to

```
Ball(int x, int y, Graphics g) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.g = g;
}
```

And then when initialising your ball object, you pass the graphics object from the applet:

```
BallList.add(new Ball(startX, startY, getGraphics()));
```